# ¿Cómo obtener el siguiente indice del indice actual en un array de objetos?

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs

Tengo el siguiente objeto de arrays:

```
const cursos = {

    "nombre":"Trading Básico",
    "cantidad_modulos": 2,
    "modulos": [
     {
       "titulo_modulo": "Introducción al Trading",
       "id_modulo": 1,
       "videos": [
        {
         "id_modulo": 1, 
         "url_video": "785288157?h=3fbc0461a1",
         "titulo_video": "1. ¿Qué es el trading?",
         "videoDesbloqueado": true,
         "videoFinalizado": true
        },

        {
         "titulo_video": "2. Historia del trading",
         "id_modulo": 1,
         "url_video": "785636573?h=727a4dc53f",
         "videoDesbloqueado": false,
         "videoFinalizado": false
        }
       ]
     },

    {
       "titulo_modulo": "¿Por qué aprender Trading?",
       "id_modulo": 2,
       "videos": [
        {
         "id_modulo": 2, 
         "url_video": "785795925?h=18d1281b95",
         "titulo_video": "1. Explicación de ...",
         "videoDesbloqueado": false,
         "videoFinalizado": false
        }
       ]
     }
   ],
}
```

Y el siguiente objeto:

```
const videoActual =
{
"videoDesbloqueado": true,
"id_modulo": 1,
"url_video": "785288157?h=3fbc0461a1",
"titulo_video": "1. ¿Qué es el trading?",
"videoFinalizado": true
}
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es mapear para que se visualicen de esta manera el contenido de cursos, entonces tendrías MÓDULO X y dentro los títulos de los videos, como se ve en esta imágen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito hacer es poder obtener el siguiente video al cual estoy seleccionando, ya que, por defecto todos los videos deberían de estar DESHABILITADOS excepto el primero, y a medida que vaya finalizando el video ACTUAL, desbloquear el que sigue, estaba intentando hacer lo siguiente:

```
for (let i in cursos.modulos) {
      for (let j in cursos.modulos[i].videos) {
        if (
        // Si el objeto videoActual.titulo_video es igual al objeto.titulo_video que encuentre en el recorrido de todos los videos
          cursos.modulos[i].videos[j].titulo_video ==
          videoActual.titulo_video
        ) {
          console.log("siguiente curso");
          guardarVideoSiguiente(cursos.modulos[i].videos[parseInt(j) + 1]);
          console.log(videoSiguiente);
        }
      }
```

Estoy obteniendo el video **ACTUAL** (supongamos que es el que tiene el objeto **videoActual**) y a ese video le sumo el índice (**j**) para poder obtener el que sigue, hasta ahí todo bien.
**El problema** surge cuando ingresa al siguiente módulo (**2**) el indice comienza nuevamente desde 0 entonces ahí ya no debería sumarse j sino empezar de nuevo, ¿cómo podría hacer para solucionarlo? ¡Muchas gracias por su tiempo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es para probar si el video `j + 1` existe.

De lo contrario, restablezca `j` e incremente `i` usando variables temporales `a` y `b`.

```js
const cursos = {
  nombre: "Trading Básico",
  cantidad_modulos: 2,
  modulos: [
    {
      titulo_modulo: "Introducción al Trading",
      id_modulo: 1,
      videos: [
        {
          id_modulo: 1,
          url_video: "785288157?h=3fbc0461a1",
          titulo_video: "1. ¿Qué es el trading?",
          videoDesbloqueado: true,
          videoFinalizado: true
        },

        {
          titulo_video: "2. Historia del trading",
          id_modulo: 1,
          url_video: "785636573?h=727a4dc53f",
          videoDesbloqueado: false,
          videoFinalizado: false
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      titulo_modulo: "¿Por qué aprender Trading?",
      id_modulo: 2,
      videos: [
        {
          id_modulo: 2,
          url_video: "785795925?h=18d1281b95",
          titulo_video: "1. Explicación de ...",
          videoDesbloqueado: false,
          videoFinalizado: false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

// Demo con el video #2
const videoActual = {
  titulo_video: "2. Historia del trading",
  id_modulo: 1,
  url_video: "785636573?h=727a4dc53f",
  videoDesbloqueado: false,
  videoFinalizado: false
};

for (let i in cursos.modulos) {
  for (let j in cursos.modulos[i].videos) {
    if (
      // Si el objeto videoActual.titulo_video es igual al objeto.titulo_video que encuentre en el recorrido de todos los videos
      cursos.modulos[i].videos[j].titulo_video == videoActual.titulo_video
    ) {
      console.log("actual curso");
      console.log(cursos.modulos[i].videos[j].titulo_video);
      
      // Mira aqui
      let a = i
      let b = j + 1
      if(!cursos.modulos[a].videos[b]){
        a++
        b = 0
      }
      // Condition para el ultimo video
      if(!cursos.modulos[a]){
        console.log("El curso ha terminado. ¡Felicidades!")
        break;
      }
      console.log("siguiente curso");
      console.log(cursos.modulos[a].videos[b].titulo_video);
      // guardarVideoSiguiente(cursos.modulos[i].videos[parseInt(j) + 1]);
      // console.log(videoSiguiente);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto!! Y cómo haría en el caso de que se encuentre en cualquier otro video que no sea el último? Por defecto debería ser j+1

Comment: Si! Por defecto `b` es el indicio del proximo video en `let b = j + 1`.

Comment: Disculpa, te hago una última consulta. ¿Cómo podría hacer si ya no tengo más módulos ni videos? Para ya no hacer nada. Es decir, me encuentro en el último video del último módulo

Comment: Agregué una condición para el caso en que no haya un módulo siguiente. ;)